# asp.net open source solution to "Adding a row to a specific SQL table"?

Tags: asp.net, sql, open-source, ado.net

I'm doing a web interface using asp.net, where user can add a row to a table in a SQL database. It's the same as add a row directly in MS access. It seems I'm reinventing the wheels.

So is there any open source solutions or classes that can reduce my work? Like the validation part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if that fits your needs, but I would recommend you to have a look at the  [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) by [Sam Saffron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron). Technically you can send any kind of SQL statements and therefore also add rows. It does not have a strict validation implemented but it uses [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) for syntax highlighting.

To get an idea about it you can check it out [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Hope that helps.

**Update**

If it's an "Access like" interface I would recommend you to have a look at the ASP.NET's [DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ASPNET_DataGrid.aspx) or the newer [DataView](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article180.aspx).

Comment: About the web interface I'm working on: "It's the same as adding a row directly in MS access."

Comment: Got it! So no direct SQL statements. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I got stuck again... I've asked another quation here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7550272/390014

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if i'm wrong. I do remember SQL server having a web management tool that allows you to modify SQL databases like an installed management component.