# can't add a .accde MS access file(located outside the project folder) as AccessDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm pretty sure that the .accde file does exist. I noticed that VS asks for .mdb file, but a .accde  is also a MS Access generated database file.

Here is the screenshot(hope it helps):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN [AccessDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.accessdatasource.aspx) page.

> The AccessDataSource class does not support connecting to Access
>   databases that are protected by a user name or password, because you
>   cannot set the ConnectionString property. If your Access database is
>   protected by a user name or password, use the `SqlDataSource` control to
>   connect to it so that you can specify a complete connection string.

So the .accde is protected in terms of security. Try use `SqlDataSource`.

Comment: @draw - I'm sure because I've used .accde in my local project many times. While configuring the SqlDataSource at Add Connection dialog, click on Advanced to set Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0